# How to keep "git pull" from deleting local files

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a WordPress project with developers and am running into an issue with `git pull`. Here's an event log to explain what caused the issue:

1. The WordPress core files were committed and pushed to Github.
2. WordPress core files were added to `.gitignore` and then these files were deleted from the repository.
3. Now every time I do a `git pull`, those core files are deleted from my local repository.

I am able to recover these core files using a backup, but it's going to be a pain to do after every `git pull`. What would be the best way to get git to actually ignore these files and not delete them from my local with every `git pull`? I don't have any sensitive data committed, so there's no need to remove them from the history completely.

I found another Stackoverflow post that seems to give a good method for removing unwanted files from a repository: `git rm --cached [filenames]`. I believe this would have prevented the issue if we had done this instead of deleting files, but since files have already been deleted, I'm not sure what the best path forward is at this point.

Comment: They shouldn’t be deleted *every* time you pull, just the first time.

Comment: To echo @Ry- 's comment. If a commit consists of deleting some files, naturally when you pull the commit it will delete the files. But you are not going to pull that commit over and over, when you pull in future, you will already have that commit, so practically this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git stash`. This will save your local modifications and you can then later use them.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the troublesome files (just put them in some folder outside of git's awareness) and pull. The files are deleted from the worktree. Now put the files back where they were.

Why does that work? Well, you pull, and the most recent commit, the one you just pulled, lacks these files. So they are no longer in git's purview; they are not in the most recent commit, so they are not in the index. Now you put the files back. But now when git asks itself what you've done recently, and it sees that you've got these files in the worktree that are not in the index, it doesn't care, because you've told git to ignore them.

And of course this won't be a problem with *future* pulls, because these files are never going to be committed to git again. It's ignoring them, so it won't `add` them to a commit automatically, and *you* are going to be careful not to `add` them to a commit explicitly.